# usage of s possession with 'its'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I wonder which one is the correct form of usage.

The first choice is: "we let X **denotes** its cost".

Or, the second: "we let X **denote** its cost"?

I think it is the first option, but I don't know the rule.

Comment: Would you say 'They let John have a glass of wine' or 'They let John has a glass of wine'? This is a complex catenation, requiring the bare infinitive (_have_ or, in your example, _denote_).

Comment: The title of this question is a bit confusing. Your question seems to be about the use of "s" as a verb suffix, not as a possessive suffix (the possessive word "its" is the same in both sentences you give; the word that changes is the verb "denote"/"denotes").

Comment: This doesn’t have to do with the word “its”. It’s simply a direct object and an infinitive verb.

Comment: It must be “denote” (not “denotes”). But ‘denote’ is not the right word. Do you mean ‘decide’, or ‘stipulate’ or ‘suggest’?

Comment: @Tuffy: If it's a math problem, and the cost is being represented by the variable *X*, then *"We let X denote its cost"* is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised to correct an error (thanks to *Peter Shor* for picking this up)**

The second choice is correct.

> we let X denote its cost

The conjugation of *denote* is

- I denote
- You denote
- He/she/it denotes
- We denote
- They denote

If the subject were *X* then the construction would be the active form

> X denotes its cost

as *he/she/it denotes*.

In the first choice,

> we let X denotes its cost

the construction uses the modal verb *let* with the subject *we*; the sentence takes the passive form and the verb *to let* is conjugated. The main verb *denote* remains in the infinitive form of *to denote*.

A similar example might be:

> James mows the lawn (*he mows*).

vs.

> We let James mow the lawn (*we let ... mow*) or I let James mow the lawn (*I let ... mow*).

or

> He lets James mow the lawn (he lets ... mow)